# Using a local json/geojson file from javascript a custom plugin

Tags: javascript, drupal, geojson, drupal-modules

I pretty new with Drupal and I am writing a custom map module.
My module work fine, I can dispay my map and informations but I wrote the calling of my geojson with an hard path and I didn't find in the documentation how to call with relative/dynamic path my file to make possible to deploy my module on other website.

I think I must use route but I don't understand how that could work.

So here my code :
my **javascript** (carto_annuaire.js), this is the first line my real problem

```
var url =  "/drupal-site/recommended-project/web/modules/custom/carto_conseillers/src/geojson/annuaire_cf.geojson";

var centerProj = new ol.proj.transform([1.33333,47.583328], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

const source = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: url,
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  });

const view = new ol.View({
                       center: centerProj,
                       zoom: 8
                       });

const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: source,
  style: function (feature) {
    const color = feature.get('color') || '#c7c7c7';
    style.getFill().setColor(color);
    return style;
  },
});
```

My module.**librairies.yml**

```
carto_annuaire:
  js:
    js/carto_annuaire.js: {}
  dependencies:
    # - core/drupal
  css:
    theme:
      css/carto_annuaire.css: {}

openlayer:
  remote: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/
  version: 7.2.2
  license:
    name: BSD 2-Clause License
    url: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/LICENSE.md
    gpl-compatible: true
  js: 
    https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.2.2/dist/ol.js: { type: external }
```

my module.**routing.yml**

```
carto_conseillers.content:
  path: '/carto_conseillers'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\carto_conseillers\Controller\CartoConseillersController::content'
    _title: 'Une page exemple avec un contenu simple'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  core: 8.x
```

and my **ModuleController.php**

```
namespace Drupal\carto_conseillers\Controller;  

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase; 
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Html;

class CartoConseillersController {
    
  public function content() {
     
      
    return array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => t('<div id="map" class="map"></div>
            <div id="info">&nbsp;</div>
            <div id="popup"></div>'),
        '#attached' => array(
                    'library' => array(
                        'carto_conseillers/openlayer',
                        'carto_conseillers/carto_annuaire',
                    )
            ),
    );
  }
  
}
```

Any clue is welcome.

Thanks for your time.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I find out how to resolve as it was explain there :
[Attaching configurable JavaScript](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/creating-modules/adding-assets-css-js-to-a-drupal-module-via-librariesyml#configurable)

In the controller just add this line :

```
  $block['#attached']['drupalSettings']['myVar'] = 'myPath';
```

and in the javascript you can access to the value via

```
var url = drupalSettings.myVar;
```